# Error with implement map within template c++

Tags: c++, templates, dictionary

I need to use a map with various type within es int,int or char,int or char,char....

This is my c++ code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include<map>

using namespace std;

template< class A, class B >
class MyClass {

private:        
    std::map<A,B> DatMap;        

public:
    MyClass<K,T>(){
        DatMap = 0;
    }

    ~MyClass(){
        delete DatMap;
    }

    void DatInsert( A k ,B v ) {
        DatMap.insert( std::pair<A,B>( k, v) );
    }
};

int main(){
    DatMap<int,int> datmap1();
    diz1.DatInsert();
}
```

I found this error on:  `diz1.DatInsert();` line

the error is:

```
error: request for member ‘DatInsert’ in ‘datmap1’, which is of non-class type ‘DatMap<int, int>()’|
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: http://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/ctors#empty-parens-in-object-decl

Answer (score 3):

This is a function declaration:

```
// functon datamap1, returns DatMap<int, int>
DatMap<int,int> datmap1();
```

You need

```
DatMap<int,int> datmap1;
```

Alternatively, this syntax is valid since C++11

```
DatMap<int,int> datmap1{};
```

Comment: now it work but send me an error in destroyer...  ~MyClass(){
        delete DatMap;
        }

Comment: @OmgDatProblem `DatMap` is not a pointer, so calling `delete` on it yields a compiler error. You can safely remove the destructor. You don't need it.

Comment: He can't call anything on `DatMap` it's not a class externally available in main :-\

Comment: What's that saying about things coming in 3's? Congrats on the 100K by the way!

Answer (score 1):

Vlad and Jauncho make good points but have both missed another error

`DatMap<int,int> datmap1();` isn't valid also because there is no public type `DatMap` exposed. The class is `MyClass`

You should be saying:

```
MyClass<int,int> datmap1; // or datmap1{};
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several errors in the code.

For example identifiers K and T used in this code snippet

```
    MyClass<K,T>(){
    DatMap = 0;

    }
```

are undefined. Also the assignment DataMap by zero is invalid.

You shall not delete DatMap in destructor

```
    ~MyClass(){
    delete DatMap;
    }
```

because DatMap is not a pointer.

These both statements in main

```
DatMap<int,int> datmap1();
diz1.DatInsert();
```

are invalid. The first one is a declaration of a function that shall not be compiled. And the second statement contains call of member function DatInsert without arguments. You defined the function as having two parameters

```
void DatInsert(A k ,B v){
        DatMap.insert(std::pair<A,B>(k,v));
        }
```

so you need to provide two arguments.